# Inequality on six variables

Tags: inequality, examples-counterexamples

Let  $\ \displaystyle x,y,z,x',y',z'$ positive real numbers such that $$xy+xz+yz=1$$ $$x'y'+x'z'+y'z'=1$$
Prove that:

$$xx'+yy'+zz'\geq 1$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's wrong!

Try $x=y'\rightarrow0^+$, $z=z'=\frac{1}{2}$ and $y=x'\rightarrow2$.